# combining two sql queries in one statement

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

l have a list of students score, i want to find the rank for each student according to his average

here is the table 
[image]

steps to find the student rank.

1. create the view of average score for each student

   ```
     CREATE VIEW mid_view as 
     SELECT *,AVG(score) as score from midterm_result group by student_id
   ```

[image]

2.. find the rank

```
     SELECT * , @rank := if( @last = average, @rank , @seq ) AS rank, @seq := @seq +1,   
     @last := average
    FROM mid_view
    ORDER BY average DESC
```

result is 
  [image]

my target is to reduce the steps, i want to reach at final result without creating the **mid_view**

How can i combine these to queries in single statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just include the first query as a sub query of the second one:

```
SELECT m.*, @rank := if(@last = average, @rank, @seq) AS rank, 
       @seq := @seq +1, @last := average
FROM 
(
  SELECT *, AVG(score) as score 
  from midterm_result 
  group by student_id
) m
ORDER BY average DESC
```